# ¿Como obtener el tamaño de un array con php7?

Tags: php, web, php7

Como obtengo el tamaño de un array en la ultima versión de php, debo saber si se esta obteniendo mas un valor en las consultas a las bases de datos pero la clase count() ya no funciona en la ultima versión, ¿con que la reemplazo?

Comment: Es importante que muestres el código de lo que has realizado, para poder ayudarte. Intenta con sizeof().

Comment: `count` no esta deprecado lo puedes ver en la documentación http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php debes colocar tu codigo, a lo mejor estas intentado usar `count` sobre un arreglo que posee un nivel mas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias probar lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$array = array( "hi", "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

o prueba

```
if(sizeof($result) > 0){
     echo "array size is greater then zero";
}else{
   echo "array size is zero";
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo para responder. Siempre tienes la opción de editar, no es necesario que aportes una nueva respuesta a pesar que son diferentes. Por otra parte como sugerencia es mejor esperar que coloquen lo que han intentado, ya que a veces el error es por tipeo o mal uso de la función o elemento asociado a la pregunta

Comment: Vale, lo haré a la siguiente respuesta que tenga en mente.

Comment: Listo. Ya moví la segunda respuesta a la primera.

Answer (score 3):

Saludos puedes hacerlo de multiples formas:

la mas básica supongamos el siguiente array:

```
$miArray[0] = 10;
$miArray[1] = 20;
$miArray[2] = 30;
echo count($miArray);
//resultado
3
```

ahora bien supongamos la misma función **count** con otro array:

```
$comida = array('frutas' => array('naranja', 'plátano', 'manzana'),
                'verduras' => array('zanahoria', 'col', 'guisante'));
echo count($comida);
//resultado
2
```

bien para este ejemplo si yo deseara tener de manera global todos sus elementos seria:

```
$comida = array('frutas' => array('naranja', 'plátano', 'manzana'),
                'verduras' => array('zanahoria', 'col', 'guisante'));

// Cuenta recursiva
echo count($comida, COUNT_RECURSIVE); 
// resultado
 8
```

y obtienes el mismo resultado cuando usas **sizeof**.

Espero te ayude y para mayor detalle:

[Count](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php)

[sizeof](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sizeof.php)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!